# Add error bars to scatter plot that shows different categories sorted by colour

Tags: matplotlib, categories, scatter-plot

I want to make a scatter plot using different colours to showing different categories (see image below). I managed to do it with the following code:

```
groups = df_glenaros_plot.groupby("Treatment_plot")
for name, group in groups:
    plt.plot(group["Days"], group["pH"], marker="o", linestyle="", label=name)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Now I want to add error bars to each data point but to use plt.errorbar() function I need to define x and y. How do I do this?

I tried calling X and Y the same variables I plotted (x=days, y=pH) but I get an error saying the variables have to be the same size.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using pandas plot of the grouped dataframe which you are doing inside the for loop. You will be using the `group.plot(...)` instead of `plt.plot(...)` that you are currently using or plt.errorbar() for that matter. Using the required column for `yerr` will allow you to plot the errorbars.

An example with standard seaborn tips dataset is shown below. Hope this helps.

```
import seaborn as sns ## Used only to get sample dataset
df=sns.load_dataset("tips")


groups = df.groupby("day")
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for size, group in groups:
    group.plot("size", "total_bill", yerr="tip", marker="o", linestyle="", label=size, ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

[image]